# searching content of one file in another file : python

Tags: python, search, for-loop

I am trying to search names from file 1 in file 2 and merge some data on matched lines

file1:

```
A   28  sep 1980
B   28  jan 1985
C   25  feb 1990    
D   27  march   1995
```

and file2

```
A   hyd
B   alig
C   slg 
D   raj
```

Using this:

```
import sys
data1 = open(sys.argv[1]).read().rstrip('\n')
data2 = open(sys.argv[2]).read().rstrip('\n')
list1 = data1.split('\n')
list2 = data2.split('\n')

for line in list1:
  for item in list2:
    if line.split('\t')[0] in item.split('\t')[0]:
        print(item,'\t',line.split('\t')[3])
```

Result:

```
A   hyd      1980
B   alig     1985
C   slg  1990
D   raj      1995
```

Two questions (for clarifying the concept):

1 - I was hoping that if I change the order of lines in file2, I should get smaller number  of matches but I still get all the matches. Why?

2-  Although this program serves the purpose, how memory efficient it is expected to be? please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> 1 - I was hoping that if I change the order of lines in file2, I should get smaller number of matches but I still get all the matches. Why?

Your program does a full [cross-join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of all lines, therefore you will always get full results.

> 2- Although this program serves the purpose, how memory efficient it is expected to be? please suggest.

Awful. Read only the shortest file into memory and iterate over the lines of the longer one once.

```
with open('bigfile.txt', 'r') as bigfile:
  for bigline in bigfile:
    for littleline in littlefiledata:
       ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. for file size, file 1 and 2 shall not differ much (may be 10-20%), but they are as huge as 4-10GB in size. So, my question is "what can be done to improve the performance?"

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to turn the smaller file into a dictionary rather than iterating over it repeatedly?